# How to find hardcoded strings in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, lint

Android studio lint don't work for a kotlin project.
I can't find hardcoded strings. 
What can be solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Do these steps it worked for me

- Download Android Studio 3.2 (in preview right now)
- Open find in project window (cmd + shift + F for Mac)
- Check Regex checkbox(Top right corner).
- Check file mask(next to Regex) and type `*.kt` or choose `kt` from the
  drop down.
- Type this regex `= \"\w+\"` you can see the results now.
- Search with this regex `=\"\w+\"` in case code is not formatted
  properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Edit/Find/"Find in Path" (shortcut is Cmd+Shift+F on Mac).

Then select the check on "Regex?" at the top of the "Find in Path" window and type `\"*\"` in the search input.

Then choose to search in Directory and then select the directory with kotlin files. Search separately in `/activities` and in `/fragments` (and any other directory where you might have kotlin code).

(To search for raw strings use `\"\"\"*\"`.)

[Screenshot of "Find in Path" search for strings example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf5sW.png)

I'm not sure if this is a 100% reliable solution but it worked for me. *"Analyse -> Run inspection By Name" then type "Hardcoded strings"* does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Detekt](https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt) for static analysis in Kotlin, specifically the [string literal duplication](https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt/blob/29caec95eb1a866a5e2a3fa327f07a325d0e6cc5/detekt-rules/src/main/kotlin/io/gitlab/arturbosch/detekt/rules/complexity/StringLiteralDuplication.kt).

Answer (score 0):

Ah, well actually there's an update.
Kotlin IDE does understand org.jetbrains.annotations.PropertyKey 11, but it does not always work.
I have had problems if the bundle contains more than one language.

Example:

```
fun message(@PropertyKey(resourceBundle = "Messages") id: String) =
        ResourceBundle.getBundle("Messages").getString(sid) ?: "###$id###"
```

For more visit:https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#src